# Modify flagged values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['vals'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
df['flagged'] = ['N','Y','N','N','Y']
```

What is this most idiomatic way of modifying the values column, where the flag is 'Y'. For example, add 5 to each flagged value, so that `df['vals'] == [1,7,3,4,10]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign it back

```
df.loc[df.flagged.eq('Y'),'vals']+=5

df
Out[220]: 
   vals flagged
0     1       N
1     7       Y
2     3       N
3     4       N
4    10       Y
```

Comment: This makes sense, but for multiplication it isn't as concise - so for example is there a better way of writing this? `df.loc[df['flagged'] == 'Y', 'vals'] = df.loc[df['flagged'] == 'Y', 'vals'] * 2`

Comment: ·df.loc[df['flagged'] == 'Y', 'vals'] =df.vals * 2·@max , pandas is match the index as hidden key , so the same condition one need show on the right

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try using `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['flagged'] == 'Y', 'vals'] += 5
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   vals flagged
0     1       N
1     7       Y
2     3       N
3     4       N
4    10       Y
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Not the most idiomatic, but interesting

```
df.vals += 5 * df.flagged.eq('Y')

df

   vals flagged
0     1       N
1     7       Y
2     3       N
3     4       N
4    10       Y
```